# Find the first occurence of value in an array and return key?

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

Is there a predefined function in PHP that will find the first matching occuring value in an array and return the key,

```
$ar = array(null, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 9, 0);

fn($ar, null); // 0
fn($ar, 4); // 3
fn($ar, 7); //6
```

I have looked though the manual but cannot find anything.

Comment: See [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search)

Comment: Why the downvotes, maybe to all you experienced developers this is easy, this site does not say only ask experienced questions.

Comment: Try to search in the manual first. Downvotes oftenly occurs in cases, when question shows no research attempts.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key
>   is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use
>   array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.